# jQuery button event handler doesn't change content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

Why can't this click event change text in #output? But it changes text in #output if I write button tag outside form tag.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <button id="compressStart">Start</button>
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
"use strict";

$(function () {
    $("#compressStart").click(getDecompressInput);

});

function getDecompressInput() {
    $("#output").text('Hello');
}
```

Comment: Think, what is a button in a form supposed to do, usually? Submit it (reloading the page). You need to prevent the form from being submitted, or remove the form if you don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `<button></button>` element inside the `form`, its default behavior is to submit the form.

If you want button not to `sumbit` the form, then set the attribute `type` as `button`

```
<button type="button" id="compressStart">Start</button>
```

Comment: Nice answer, I think it is the good one. But confusing: `if you don't want that, then use, button type`??  he is actually using the button type. ;)